# Find the derivative ${(x^{3} + 2)(x^{2} + 2) \over x^3+1}$

Tags: derivatives

> find the derivative $\displaystyle{{{\rm d} \over {\rm d}x}\left[% 
>  {\left(x^{3} + 2\right)\left(x^{2} + 2\right) \over x^3+1}\right]}$

This is what I have so far:
    $$(x^3+1)[(x^3+2)(x^2+2)]-[(x^3+1)](x^3+2)(x^2+2)/(x^3+1)^2$$
    $$(x^3+1)[(3x^2)(2x)]-[3x^2](x^3+2)(x^2+2)/(x^3+1)^2$$

I have the answer but I don't know how to get there:
    $$2x^7+3x^4-6x^+4x/(x^3+1)^2$$

Comment: did i edited correctly  or  have i missed something?

Comment: We can use $$x^3+2=x^3+1+1$$

Comment: Sorry, I'm still trying to figure this out.

Comment: multiply in brackets to each other,to avoid more much multiplication and then use quotient  rule

Comment: that makes a lot of sense! thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
d/dx((x³+2)(x²+2)/(x³+1)) = d/dx((x⁵+2x³+2x²+4)/(x³+1))
=((x³+1)(x⁵+2x³+2x²+4)′-(x⁵+2x³+2x²+4)(x³+1)′)/(x³+1)²
=((x³+1)(5x⁴+6x²+4x)-(x⁵+2x³+2x²+4)(3x²))/(x³+1)²
=(5x⁷+6x⁵+4x⁴+5x⁴+6x²+4x-3x⁷-6x⁵-6x⁴-12x²)/(x³+1)²
=(2x⁷+3x⁴-6x²+4x)/(x³+1)²
Now, factor the top, just to be sure nothing cancels out:
=x(2x⁶+3x³-6x+4)/(x³+1)². Nothing can cancel, so you can leave it as you had it before:
=(2x⁷+3x⁴-6x²+4x)/(x³+1)²
```

Comment: @envy  this multiplication as i told you,it better way

Comment: @MathBob.You have some typo's in the equation which follows "cancels out". It is just a detail. Cheers.

Comment: Please fix your format!

Comment: please use latex next time!

Answer (score 4):

I guess you may misunderstand how to get
$$\{(x^3+2)(x^2+2)\}^\prime.$$

You can use 
$$g^\prime(x)=(x^3+2)^\prime(x^2+2)+(x^3+2)(x^2+2)^\prime.$$

Let $$f(x)=x^3+1,g(x)=(x^3+2)(x^2+2).$$
First find $f^\prime(x),g^\prime(x)$, then set them in
$$\left\{\frac{g(x)}{f(x)}\right\}^\prime=\frac{g^\prime(x)f(x)-g(x)f^\prime(x)}{\{f(x)\}^2}.$$

Note that in general,
$$\{h(x)i(x)\}^\prime=h^\prime(x)i(x)+h(x)i^\prime(x).$$

EDIT : Since
$$g^\prime(x)=3x^2(x^2+2)+(x^3+2)\cdot 2x=5x^4+6x^2+4x,$$
yours will be
$$\frac{(5x^4+6x^2+4x)(x^3+1)-(x^3+2)(x^2+2)\cdot 3x^2}{(x^3+1)^2}.$$

Then, simplify the numerator.

Comment: @envy: Don't you think $$\{(x^3+2)(x^2+2)\}^\prime=(x^3+2)^\prime(x^2+2)^\prime?$$This is wrong.

Comment: So what do I do after I set it up? that is if I did it correctly.  $(3x^2)(2x)(x^3+1)-(x^3+2)(x^2+2)(3x)/(x^3+1)$

Comment: @envy: Did you read my answer? What you wrote is wrong. $$\{(x^3+2)(x^2+2)\}^\prime\not=(3x^2)(2x)$$

Comment: @envy: see my edit. Does this help?

Comment: Thank you so much guys for all your help. I get it now!

Answer (score 2):

you are complicating things,please multiplying together in brackets and then use derivative rule for quotient  polynomials,if you multiply  in brackets,you get

$x^5+2*x^3+2*x^2+4$

so finally you have this quotient polynomials

$(x^5+2*x^3+2*x^2+4)/(x^3+1)$

now please consider  that  $d(f/g)/dx=(f'*g-g'*f)/(g^2)$

http://www.math.hmc.edu/calculus/tutorials/quotient_rule/

EDITED:

ok suppose that we are trying to derivative following  one

$(x^3+4)(x^2+x+1)$

now you can use product rule  and make derivative,but is not better to multiply this two polynomial on each other  and then make derivative? what do you  think?

Comment: Your answer is good and right. I upvoted for supporting you !

Answer (score 1):

One might also notice that
$$
\frac{x^3+2}{x^3+1}=1+\frac1{x^3+1}
$$
to simplify before using the quotient rule:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\frac{(x^3+2)(x^2+2)}{x^3+1}
&=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(x^2+2+\frac{x^2+2}{x^3+1}\right)\\
&=2x+\frac{2x(x^3+1)-3x^2(x^2+2)}{(x^3+1)^2}\\
&=2x+\frac{2x-6x^2-x^4}{(x^3+1)^2}
\end{align}
$$